# Why are some ES6 imports globally available, while others are not?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I use standard ES6 imports in a react project that is built with Webpack.

For example, at the top of my files will be statements like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
```

I found that if multiple files use `React`, I need to import it in each file.
But I only need to import `lodash` in one file, and it is available everywhere.

Why the difference?

Comment: lodash might be sticking itself on the global object, or you have a webpack config to shim underscore as global. You should always import libraries you need explicitly in the files that need them, and use tools like eslint to warn when you don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a lodash specific issue - when imported using Webpack, it can leak into the global window.

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1798